# Web Scraping Linkedin Profiles: Cannot pick all links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Following is the code being used:

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r')

sub = 'linkedin.com'

for linkedin_url in linkedin_urls:
    tag = linkedin_url.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    URL = tag.get_attribute('href')

    if sub in URL:
       try:
          driver.get(URL)
          sleep(5)
          driver.back()
          driver.get(URL)
       except:
          pass
```

- *Following is the error i get:*

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 25, in 
>       tag = linkedin_url.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\deepankar.garg\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 305, in find_element_by_tag_name
>       return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\deepankar.garg\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 659, in find_element
>       {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\deepankar.garg\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 633, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\deepankar.garg\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\deepankar.garg\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is
>   not attached to the page document   (Session info:
>   chrome=79.0.3945.79)

**Following is the output before *IF* condition:**

https://www.linkedin.com/in/elena-grewal

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Data-Science-and-Analytics

https://www.edureka.co/blog/what-is-data-science/

**Following is the output after *IF* condition:**

https://www.linkedin.com/in/elena-grewal

https://in.linkedin.com/in/bsatya

https://www.linkedin.com/in/kylemckiou

I know what the error means, but i do not know how to resolve it. I just wish to open each link in the "if" (true) condition in a separate web browser. The links present in the above "after IF" condition is what i wish to open in each tab.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`StaleElementReferenceException`  comes when the element is no longer present in the div or has become stale. In your scenario as you are coming back to the url after navigating to the next page, the element has become stale when you are trying to access it again.

To resolve it, you need to fetch the element again before accessing it.
You can do it like:

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r')

sub = 'linkedin.com'

while i < len(linkedin_urls): 
    tag = linkedin_urls[i].find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    URL = tag.get_attribute('href')
    i += 1

    if sub in URL:
       try:
          driver.get(URL)
          sleep(5)
          driver.back()
          driver.get(URL)
          # Fetching the element again here
          linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('r') 
       except:
          pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sameer! But, what you suggested is same as driver.back(). Moreover, i did try what you said, but doesnt do any good! It goes to the back page and re-fetches the first link, whereas i want it to fetch each link.

Comment: @DeepankarGarg please try the updated code, i have used index now while fetching the urls, so this time, it will fetch the second link in the second iteration and third in third iteration and so on and so forth.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it still does not work! It still gives me just one profile! The main problem occurs inside IF condition. Outside IF i have roughly 15 links, after IF condition, i get 10 links. I have to somehow run an iterative loop on those 10 links in order to get them to open each profile in a new window.

Comment: I have edited my question. Maybe that will help now!

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

I got the solution. Following is something that i tried and it worked:

```
all_urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > a")

urls = []
for elem in all_urls:
text = elem.text
url = elem.get_property('href')
if "linkedin.com" in elem.text:
    urls.append(url) 
#print(urls)
for url in urls:
   driver.get(url)
   sleep(2)
   print(url)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!